# Expresso Store - Register Member not working

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Can't seem to get the register member on Expresso Store v2.4.1 to work.

I've the following but submitting the form does nothing (stay on same page):

```
{if logged_out}
    <fieldset id="register_member">
    <legend>Member Account</legend>

    {field:register_member} <label for="register_member">Register Member Account?</label>

    <!-- These fields are optional -->
    <div class="toggle">
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        {field:password}
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
        {field:password_confirm}
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        {field:username}
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="screen_name">Screen Name</label>
        {field:screen_name}
      </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    {/if}
```

Do I need anything else for this to work. I have allow  new member registrations set to yes in the member preferences?

I've even tried the register_member="yes" on the checkout form which allowed me through to the next page but still no account has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Ok needed register_member="yes" on the checkout form. NOTE: The member account only gets created if the order is successful.